# My Application Crashed by this Error : Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, winforms

I have developed a winform application (using vs 2010 C#).in this application i used a com object and this object has some events.one of them is:

```
void a_Received(object sender, ReceivedEvent e)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = e.Message;
}
```

Another part of code that fire this event is like this:

```
 private void btnSendMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyComObject obj = new MyComObject();
    obj.SendCommand(txtCommand.Text);
}
```

so some times based on command , 2 or more message recieved Simultaneously by event and i got this exception:
**Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt**

and if only one message come (by event) every thing is good.

so what is the problem.
what can i do?

**EDIT:**
Exception will happen when all message that recieved processed (and processed successfully) at the end of code (I mean after } of event).

StackTrace :

> `at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageA(MSG& msg)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>   at IranAir.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Gabriel\Program.cs:line 18
>   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()`

Comment: At what point you are getting this error and is the com object multi threaded?

Comment: How does this stacktrace relate to your original question?

Comment: i cant understand.what do you mean?

Comment: Nowhere in that stack trace does it say Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Comment: this is the details of exception.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two threads writing to the same file simultaneously. That's why if you try to delete a file that's in use, Windows Pops-up saying "this file is in use." When one file is being used windows is *protecting* the file from being obstructed by another process. You need to make sure only one message is being written at a time. Set up a queue or check if the file is being used. See this post:

[Is there a way to check if a file is in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use)